# select random file from directory

Tags: c#, .net, file, random

I've seen a few examples but none so far in C#, what is the best way to select a random file under a directory?

In this particular case I want to select a wallpaper from "C:\wallpapers" every 15 or so minutes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[select random file from directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742887/select-random-file-from-directory)

```
private string getrandomfile2(string path)
    {
        string file = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            var extensions = new string[] { ".png", ".jpg", ".gif" };
            try
            {
                var di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
                var rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.*").Where( f => extensions.Contains( f.Extension.ToLower()));
                Random R = new Random();
                file = rgFiles.ElementAt(R.Next(0,rgFiles.Count())).FullName;
            }
            // probably should only catch specific exceptions
            // throwable by the above methods.
            catch {}
        }
        return file;
    }
```

Comment: Catching exceptions and silently ignoring them is bad. You should either handle the exception and return something useful, or not catch them at all.

Answer (score 30):

Get all files in an array and then retrieve one randomly

```
var rand = new Random();
var files = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\wallpapers","*.jpg");
return files[rand.Next(files.Length)];
```

Comment: I tried this code snippet and its working fine but it is only searching in the folder wallpapers and not searching any sub-folders inside wallpapers. How to modify the code to do that as well?

Comment: Consider passing SearchOption.AllDirectories as a third argument to the GetFiles method.

Answer (score 10):

If you're doing this for wallpapers, you don't want to just select a file at random because it won't appear random to the user.

What if you pick the same one three times in a row?  Or alternate between two?

That's "random," but users don't like it.

See this post about how to [display random pictures in a way users will like](http://blog.asmartbear.com/blog/2007/12/18/not-in-the-cards.html).

Comment: When shuffling you should probably also account for the case that a file gets deleted or added to the directory (in which case you need to re-shuffle).

Answer (score 6):

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\dev").GetFiles();
int index = new Random().Next(0, files.Length);

Console.WriteLine(files[index].Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

why not just:

1. get the files into an array
2. use the Random class to select a number that is random between 0 and files.Length
3. Grab the file from the array using the random number as the index

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Directory.GetFiles(...)` to get the array of filenames and use the `Random` class to select a random file.

Answer (score 0):

Just my 5 cents, code for an mvc action, using cookies so we do not repeat the same filename twice:

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        //-------------------------------------------------------------
        public async Task<ActionResult> RandomBackground()
        //-------------------------------------------------------------
        {
            var basePath = "~/Content/images/backgrounds";
            var dir = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(basePath);

            var rand = new Random();
            var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.jpg");
            if (files!=null)
            {
                var cookie = "Background";
                var pickedFile = "";
                var fileName = "";
                var oldFilename = "";
                while ((oldFilename == fileName) && files.Count<string>()>1)
                {
                    oldFilename = ReadControllerCookie(cookie);
                    pickedFile = files[rand.Next(files.Length)];
                    fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pickedFile);
                }
                SaveControllerCookie(cookie, fileName);
                return Content(fileName);
            }
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

Used as:

```
<img src="~/Content/images/backgrounds/@Html.Action("RandomBackground", "YourControllerName")">
```