# Getting Random File from Directory Tree

Tags: c#, linq, directory-tree

So I can't seem to find a good example of this anywhere.  I found a good example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742887/select-random-file-from-directory) question of picking a random file from a directory, but I need to pick a random file from a directory tree (of unknown depth).  This code gets a random file from 1 directory, but I have been perplexed as to how to extend it to all sub directories as well, I'm sure one of you LINQ gurus out there can help me craft something.

```
var extensions = new string[] { ".mp3" };
var di = new DirectoryInfo(MusicPath);
var rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.*")
    .Where( f => extensions.Contains( f.Extension.ToLower() ));
int fileCount = rgFiles.Count();
if (fileCount > 0)
{
    int x = this.Generator.Next( 0, fileCount );  //Generator is 'Random' object
    file = rgFiles.ElementAt(x).FullName;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
var random = new Random(); // this should be placed in a static member variable, but is ok for this example
var fileNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp", "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var randomFile = fileNames[random.Next(0, fileNames.Length)];
```

Comment: Man that was ridiculously easy, glad I asked was in the middle of crafting a recursive mess.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. I always try to solve using Directory / File rather than DirectoryInfo / FileInfo.

Comment: +1, and this is also the fastest possible. I tried Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories).Skip(random.Next(0, fileCount).First() but apparently the only way on .NET to find the fileCount is by counting the GetFiles result :)