# Select random file from folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-io, directory

My folder contain more then 100 zip files. I want to select random 6 zip file from a folder.

I try:

```cs
DirectoryInfo test = new DirectoryInfo(@ "C:\test").GetFiles();
foreach(FileInfo file in test.GetFiles()) {

  Random R = new Random(); //try to apply random logic but fail.

  if (file.Extension == ".zip") {
    string a = "";
    for (int ListTemplate = 0; ListTemplate < 6; ListTemplate++) {
      a += file.FullName; //Want to choose random 6 files.
    }

  }
}
```

Is there any way to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [select random file from directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742685/select-random-file-from-directory)

Comment: you don't use the random anywhere, just pick a random number between 0 and `GetFiles().Count - 1`... (no need for the foreach)

Comment: I search and found that link but it select all files.Not duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you want to randomize the order in which the files are being sorted.

Using the sort shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/108836/51) (you can use the more cryptographic approach as well if you want)

```
var rnd = new System.Random();
var files = Directory.GetFiles(pathToDirectory, "*.zip")
                     .OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())
                     .Take(numOfFilesThatYouWant);
```

You can then evaluate `files` in your `foreach`. It should give the number of files that you want to process, in a random order.

Comment: You could remove the `.where` via using the extension version of [`GetFiles("*.zip")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Also, to create a string `a` with all the file names, use `string.Join`, not a loop, for example `string a = string.Join("\r\n", files.Select(x => x.FullName));`.